# Как добавить новое свойство в объект JS?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть объект, я в него хочу добавлять новые свойства так, чтобы каждый раз повторно не вызывать функцию и предыдущее свойство не перезаписывалось.

```
function addnewCategory(category, word) {
    dict[category] = [word]
}

var dict = {
    vegitables: ['potato']
}

addnewCategory('fruits')
console.log(dict)
addnewCategory('clothes') // сейчас чтобы добавить свойство в объект, нужно повторно вызвать функцию, иначе она перезапишется. 
console.log(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void (dict[category] ||= []).push(word)
```

Comment: Таким образом в массив добавляется значение. Мне кстати это тоже нужно, спасибо огромное. Но требовалось мне в объект добавить всю связку ключ:значение, при этом чтобы добавленная ранее связка не перезаписывалась. Сейчас так: при вызове функции addnewCategory('fruits', 'apple') в объект записывается новое свойство fruits:apple, если я заменю ключ и значение в этом же вызове, fruits:apple сотрется. Свойств в объекте по-прежнему будет два. Хотелось бы каждый раз не вызывать функцию.

Comment: @user430413, во-первых, ничего не понятно. Во-вторых, описанное явно не соответствует коду из вопроса. В-третьих, функция тут вообще не при чём. Ну жди, может кто-то ещё ответит.

Comment: «Данный ответ отмечен как «низкокачественный» из-за длины и содержимого.» — и ведь не ошибся движок: действительно, ответу очень не помешало бы объяснение, что именно в ответе предлагается.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, ну ты и откопал...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, я тут так и не понял, чего хотел автор, потому что этот ответ его не устроил... А старьё само в очередь вроде не должно добавляться, но при этом следов отправки туда вроде нет - странно...

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, да, это я в таймлайне уже нашёл, а вот как он туда попал почти через 4 месяца после написания?

Comment: так что насчёт улучшения качества ответа путём вставки объяснений?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, так он же не подошёл даже. Хочешь, сам дополни.